# Where can I look for a cruise (and information about it) to the Bahamas or the Caribbean?

Tags: cruising, caribbean, bahamas, ships

My wife and I are going to be on the May 17 in New York city and we would like to take a cruise to the Bahamas or to the Caribbean, If you can recommend for a good site to search for a fair price and any other information that would be wonderful..

Is there a site similar to [kayak.com](http://www.kayak.com) for cruises?

Comment: this seems a lot like a shopping question, no? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I don't think it is a shopping question. 0x90 is asking for a site where he can search for cheap sea cruises. That's essentially the same as asking for a site to search for air tickets, and we have allowed a lot of such questions.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the OP couldn't find a cruise specific site. Just Google Cruise and you get like a million of them.

Comment: @JohnFx hey I have googled it of course but I came with very expensive cruises and the first result seems ephemeral, maybe beacuse I am googling it from another country...

Comment: The first results are mostly ads. Look down a few results and find a site like vacationstogo that aggregate cruises from a lot of different places. Also, check the cruise companies' web sites directly.

Comment: I'm in favour of opening this again, as it's not a direct shopping question - like Royal Caribbean vs Disney cruises or 'what's the best cruise?' - he's trying to find a kayak equivalent for cruises.  Sure he can google 'cruise' like @JohnFx suggests, but that won't necessarily find kayak if you google 'airline' - it's the comparison site he's after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several:

- [CheapCruises](http://www.cheapcruises.com)
- [Cruises.com](http://cheap.cruises.com)
- [Cruise.com](http://www.cruise.com)
- [CruiseCheap](http://www.cruisecheap.com)
- [Travelocity](http://www.travelocity.com/Cruises)